# Let $G$ be a nilpotent and $H<G$. Is $H$ a Nilpotent?

Tags: abstract-algebra

This is my question: Let $G$ be a  nilpotent and $H<G$. Is $H$ a Nilpotent? Can you HELP me with the proof? Thank you so much..

Comment: What definition of nilpotent group are you using?

Comment: An element of a ring is nilpotent if $a^n=0$ for some $n$.